# Using grep (on Windows) to find a string contained by 's

Tags: windows, bash, shell, sed, grep

I'm trying to write a shell script in windows, which is why I'm not using something like `awk` or `grep -o` etc.

I'm trying to parse my angular files for the controllers being used. For example, I'll have a line like this in a file.

```
widgetList.controller('widgetListController', [
```

What I want is to pull out `widgetListController`

Here's what I've got so far:

```
grep -h "[[:alpha:]]*Controller[[:alpha:]]*" C:/workspace/AM/$file | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -h "[[:alpha:]]*Controller[[:alpha:]]*"
```

It works decently well, but it will pull out the entire line like so:

`widgetList.controller('widgetListController',` rather than just the word.

Also in instances where the controller is formatted as so:

`controller     : 'widgetListController',`

It returns `'widgetListController',`

How can I adjust this to simply return whatever is between the 's? I've tried various ways of escaping that character but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Does your `grep` not have `-o` option?

Comment: @anubhava Unfortunately it does not, that's why I'm going to such great lengths with `-h` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this sed command:

```
sed "/Controller/s/.*'\([^']*\)'.*$/\1/" C:/workspace/AM/$file
```

**Output:**

```
widgetListController
```

Comment: That second line is dumping out some errors:

conditional binary operator expected and syntax error near =~

Comment: Hmm looks like your BASH doesn't support `=~`

Comment: Yes, it looks like I have `sed`

Comment: This worked with a slight modification. What I did was pipe the first half of my script into this sed command and it cleaned it up perfectly, like so: `grep -h "[[:alpha:]]*Controller[[:alpha:]]*" C:/workspace/AM/$file | sed "/Controller/s/.*'\([^']*\)'.*$/\1/"`

Without the piping this would output the rest of the file alongside the cleaned up lines which contained `Controller`. Thank you!